# Insert, upload e Update no mesmo processo

Tags: php

Bom to com um problema aqui que ja tentei resolver de varias maneiras sem exito. Segue parte que esta pegando

```
$stmt->execute();  -------> final do insert até aki ok
if (DB::lastInsertId()) {
// pego o ultimo id
$lastId = DB::lastInsertId();
// crio o diretorio
mkdir ("../img/$lastId", 0755 ); ---> ate aqui ok o diretorio e criado usando o ultimo id
---------------------> a partir daqui que esta o problema
// upload e update
// altero o nome
$filename = time() . '_' . $_FILES["imagem"]["name"];
$diretorio = '../img/$lastId/';
$filepath = '$diretorio' . $filename;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imagem"]["tmp_name"], $filepath)
// insere no bd
$sqlInsert2 = "UPDATE noticias SET imagem=$filename WHERE idnoticia=$lastId";
$stmt = DB::prepare($sqlInsert2);
$stmt->bindParam("imagem", $filename);
$stmt->execute();


 setMessage("Notícia $lastId $filename cadastrado com sucesso.");
    redirect("noticiasListar.php");
```

os demais itens das noticias estao sendo inseridos, a pasta esta sendo criada, só não esta fazendo o upload da imagem e nem o update da imagem no bd

alguma solução?

Comment: Se cada noticia tem uma imagem única, por que não salva o arquivo nomeado com o id da noticia, ou ainda dentro da pasta que você criou usando o id, porém com um nome padrão?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema está aqui:

```
$diretorio = '../img/$lastId/';
$filepath = '$diretorio' . $filename;
```

Repare nas aspas.

Ou você troca para aspas duplas ou concatena:

```
$diretorio = '../img/' . $lastId . '/';
$filepath = $diretorio . $filename;
```

Tem que colocar aspas na *query* e concatenar também:

```
$sqlInsert2 = 'UPDATE noticias SET imagem = "' . $filename . '" WHERE idnoticia = "' . $lastId . '"';
```

Comment: vou efetuar a alteração aqui e qq coisa retorno

Comment: Perfeito Lucas, estou engatinhando ainda nesse negocio de PDO, so a titulo de tirar duvida tem como fazer esse processo em uma unica vez? tipo estou querendo pegar o proximo ID antes mesmo de inserir a materia para criar a pasta . é possivel ou esse metodo que estou fazendo é o correto mesmo?

Comment: Ótimo. Não sei se tem como pegar o próximo ID, mas mesmo se tiver, não acho uma boa prática porque alguém pode inserir um registro após pegar o próximo ID e antes de inserir na tabela

Comment: a minha ideia era fazer 1 INSERT só ao inves de Fazer o INSERT e o UPDATE. Antes do insert ele pegava o proximo id, criava a pasta, fazia o upload e o insert de uma vez, mais de todo jeito ta funcionando e mais uma vez obrigado

Comment: Eu costumo usar transaction (http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.begintransaction.php) para evitar inconsistencias no banco de dados

Comment: @ArsomNolasco por que não pega o nome do arquivo antes do insert?

Comment: como disse estou engatinhando ainda, mais qual a vantagem e desvantagem de pegar antes ou depois?  @adrianosymphony $dbh->beginTransaction(); $dbh->rollBack(); Realmente sem risco de dar pepino

Comment: @ArsomNolasco no seu caso pode pegar antes, você não faz nenhuma validação se o diretório foi criado e o arquivo movido ou não, porém deveria fazer tais. Ps: quando direcionar a resposta para alguém marque a mesma, assim aparecerá uma notificação na inbox.

Comment: obrigado pelas dicas e vou seguir os conselhos